# Difference between constants defined in Go's syscall and C's stat.h

Tags: c, linux, go, constants, stat

Hello stackoverflow friends,

I am on arch linux.

I was going over the constants defined in syscall package related to permission bits as a part of my internal project, and I see that the value of a few constants that I was interested in, is different from what is defined in the stat.h.

The ones I looked into was

```
        S_IRGRP                          = 0x20
        S_IWGRP                          = 0x10
        S_IXGRP                          = 0x8
```

which is defined in https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/

whereas in linux's stat.h, the value is

```
#define S_IRGRP 00040
#define S_IWGRP 00020
#define S_IXGRP 00010
```

(https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/stat.h#L35)
These were the values I checked so far, and there may be a few more that doesn't match with the C header file.
As of now, I have declared the constants with values that matches the one in `stat.h` within my project and using it, but I am not sure why there is this difference in the values between go's syscall constants and the stat.h #define constants.

Has anyone came across this before and know why there is this difference? Are these constants used for different purposes in C and Go?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Octal is a wonderful base, isn't it?

Comment: Thank you very much @EOF I didn't realise 00040 was octal. If you can add it as an answer, I will accept it. I was under the impression that this was decimal.

Comment: Pretty sure there will be a number of duplicates, but I can't *find* that number because of terrible legacy numerical formats ;-)

Comment: @EOF Found one here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48123541/how-does-the-go-language-os-filemode-function-convert-permissions-from-integers May be you can mark it as a duplicate.